# VB6 IDE Breakpointing at weird Locations, and Jumping to Random Lines with "Step Into"

Tags: vb6, ide, breakpoints

I've been experiencing some weird things in the VB6 IDE. When I set a breakpoint on one of the functions, The IDE Pauses on the wrong Sub. If I "Step Into" and follow the code. It "Appears" to be running the correct sub, based on the property gets being accessed. If I then click Stop VB6 Crashes.

I can't Post the entire source as its closed. 
But here's the [Classes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/59t1eix1azns435/classes.rar?dl=0) that are encountering the issue. 
Along with this [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy17sw29amqoxwu/VB6Bug.avi?dl=0) Showing the bug.

In the video clip you can see, There is a breakpoint set on the "DoAutoSize" Sub. However the IDE Pauses on "OnChange". And Clicking the "Step Into" button Doesn't seem to follow the code properly.

The only thought I've had is that its related to the "Implements" Statement and that the Class that's Implementing Igui_Control isn't properly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reinstall as that is the only way to stop this.

Comment: I did a full reinstall, and still have the same problem. So this doesn't seem to be fixing it.
I should note that I had a similiar issue prior, that was caused by missing subs in the "Implementing Class". However I've checked multiple times, and everything seems like its in order. Also the issue is occurring in the class being implemented this time.